# Better "find and highlight" implementation in HTML element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out what is best and fastest implementation of a browser-like find and highlight function inside a website using JavaScript.
This function is for **one** HTML element **without** any children. Of course it can be expanded to elements with children with some simple loops. That is not part of question.
I wrote this small code to make something working here:

**CSS**

```
span.highlight{background:yellow; padding:3px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="search"/>
<p>The Ama...</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var s = document.querySelector('input[type="search"]'),
    p = document.querySelector('p'),
    find = function(){
    var words = p.innerText.split(' ');
    for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++){
        if(words[i].toLowerCase() == s.value.toLowerCase()){
            words[i] = '<span class="highlight">' + words[i] + "</span>";
            p.innerHTML = words.join(' ');
        }
        else{

        }   
    }
}
s.addEventListener('keydown', find , false);
s.addEventListener('keyup', find , false);
```

This code is working fine. Checkout live example **[here](http://jsbin.com/ebucaz)**. But this is not fast and sometimes crash the browser. How can I make this functionality with a better approach?

Please note I don't want a full code review here. So don't remind me that `querySelector` is not supported in IE7 and same things.

Comment: Is there a point in getting and lowercasing words on each call to `find()`? Why not just do that once on `onload`? My javascript-fu is pretty low, so even if it's something obvious please explain...

Comment: Because I don't wanna mess `words` array with converting it to lower case. I'm keeping element's actual text in that array

Comment: Ah yes you need the actual text to highlight it. Still I think it would be significantly faster if you've built the array once and outside of the loop, you could keep two values for each word (the lowercase to compare and the original to highlight).

Comment: It occurs to me you can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here. Something like `p.innerHTML = p.innerText.split(' ').reduce(function (prev, cur) {return prev + ' ' + ((cur.toLowerCase() === s.value.toLowerCase()) ? '<span class="highlight">' + cur + "</span>" : c;}, "")`. While so many browsers have yet to implement a fast reduce it's not the best approach, so I'm not giving it as an answer, but food for thought.

Comment: I've described here why building a selfmade highlighting function is a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery/32758672#32758672

Comment: Btw: I just want to mention that innerHTML is evil as it will destroy all events inside that element and re-create the DOM. Also innerHTML is slower than the normal createElement (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11854965/3894981) for further information). If you are searching for a solution intended for every situation you might be interested in [mark.js](https://markjs.io/).

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by optimising your code.  Simply said, loops are the danger here.

1. A `while` loop can be quicker than a `for` loop, especially in cases like this. Get the length once.
2. Avoid looking into arrays.  Do `word = words[i]` once, which is much faster.
3. You are joining in every iteration. You should join once only after you have updated your array.
4. I guess the empty `else` isn't done yet.

```
var s = document.querySelector('input[type="search"]'),
    p = document.querySelector('p'),
    find = function(){
        var words = p.innerText.split(' '),
            i = words.length,
            word = '';

        while(--i) {
            word = words[i];
            if(word.toLowerCase() == s.value.toLowerCase()){
                words[i] = '<span class="highlight">' + word + "</span>";
            }
            else{

            }   
        }

        p.innerHTML = words.join(' ');
    }

s.addEventListener('keydown', find , false);
s.addEventListener('keyup', find , false);
```

Last but surely not least, [the page you want to read](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/JavaScript_Performance_Best_Practices).

Comment: I'm curious if it would be faster to use a stack. `while (words) { word = words.pop(); …}`

Comment: There's really no need for another function call. You want to avoid those. Plus popping out the value doesn't benefit you. It's cute, but not faster I'm afraid :)

Comment: the negative while for speed is a good option likely due to its deterministic nature